# Issue with C++11 regex_search and ECMAScript syntax

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am currently working under Ubuntu, with gcc-4.9, experimenting with the C++11  library. There is clearly something that I don't understand with the (default) ECMAScript syntax for regex.

My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string test_str = "this is text containing teeext! Text! Teeeeeeeeeext! This txt should not be matched, nor this Txt";
string pattern = "([Tt][e]+xt)";

try {
    regex r(pattern, regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    smatch results;

    if (regex_search(test_str, results, r))
    {
        cout << "Found #" << results.size() << " results!" << endl;
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
                cout << results[i].str() << endl;
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "no match for " << pattern << endl;
} catch (regex_error &e) {
    cout << "what: " << e.what() << "; code: " << e.code() << endl;
}
}
```

I'd expect the regex to match "text", "teeext", "Text" and "Teeeeeeeeeext" inside the original string; but the output is:

```
Found #2 results!
text
text
```

I already tried several ways to specify the regex, such as `"[T|t]e+xt"` and variations, but nothing seems to work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The flag was a mistake, I just removed it ^_^;

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the new c++0x regex object to match repeatedly within a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586733/how-do-i-use-the-new-c0x-regex-object-to-match-repeatedly-within-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what `size()` and `[]` do on a `match_results` object. `regex_search` and `regex_match` don't apply the regex as many times as possible. They look for the *first* match. The submatches in the `match_results` object then correspond to individual groups (parenthesis subexpressions) in the regex, with index `0` corresponding to the entire match.

So in your case, it stops on the first match (`text`). That value is matched by the entire regex, and (since the entire regex is a capturing group), also by the first subgroup. That's why `size()` is `2` and both submatches return `text`.